# JPA Repository : Cannot bind parameter for timezone

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, group-by, spring-data-jpa

I have the following code in JPA repository and it works.

```
  @Query(
      value =
          "SELECT EXTRACT(HOUR FROM STO.createddate\\:\\:timestamptz at time zone 'Asia/Seoul') AS hour,\n"
              + "        COUNT(STO.id) AS count, SUM(STO.grandtotalprice) AS sum, AVG(STO.grandtotalprice) AS average\n"
              + "FROM store.storeorder AS STO\n"
              + "WHERE STO.store_id=?1 AND STO.createddate >= ?2 AND STO.createddate < ?3 AND STO.orderstatus IN ('CLOSED')\n"
              + "GROUP BY EXTRACT(HOUR FROM STO.createddate\\:\\:timestamptz at time zone 'Asia/Seoul') \n"
              + "ORDER BY hour ASC;",
      nativeQuery = true)
  List<ReportHourly> hourlyReport(
      UUID storeId, LocalDateTime from, LocalDateTime to);
```

However, when I try to input timezone as parameter like below, it fails with saying

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "createddate" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
```

```
  @Query(
      value =
          "SELECT EXTRACT(HOUR FROM STO.createddate\\:\\:timestamptz at time zone ?4) AS hour,\n"
              + "        COUNT(STO.id) AS count, SUM(STO.grandtotalprice) AS sum, AVG(STO.grandtotalprice) AS average\n"
              + "FROM store.storeorder AS STO\n"
              + "WHERE STO.store_id=?1 AND STO.createddate >= ?2 AND STO.createddate < ?3 AND STO.orderstatus IN ('CLOSED')\n"
              + "GROUP BY EXTRACT(HOUR FROM STO.createddate\\:\\:timestamptz at time zone ?4) \n"
              + "ORDER BY hour ASC;",
      nativeQuery = true)
  List<ReportHourly> hourlyReport(
      UUID storeId, LocalDateTime from, LocalDateTime to, String timeZone);
```

I am not sure why parameterization doesn't work for this case.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem here is that JDBC doesn't really know about indexed bind arguments, it only knows about `?` for binding.

This means the two occurrences fo `?4` get translated into two different bind parameters and therefore Postgres sees an expression in the select clause that is not part of the `GROUP BY` nor an aggregate function.

Since by construction the two actually are the same you should be fine wrapping the expression for hour in `MAX(...)` or any other aggregate function that returns the argument value when applied to a single row.